# Cannot save object props to parse.com table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

I have a form with a `textbox` *title*, `dropdown menu` *year* and a button. When I click the button, I want to get the values of `title` and `year` as properties to an object `Movie`. Then save them to a table on parse.com. The code below adds a recording to the table with values **undefined**.

```
<script>

function saveValues() {      // function is appended as onclick to button

var $titleValue = $('#inputTitle').val();
var $select = $('#select');
var $yearValue = $select.val();

var Movie = Parse.Object.extend("Movie");
var movie = new Movie();

// movie.set('title', $titleValue); // Doesn't work. Returns undefined
// movie.set('year', $yearValue);   // Doesn't work. Returns undefined

movie.title = $titleValue;         // Works
movie.year = $yearValue;           // Works
alert(movie.title);                // Returns the value
alert(movie.year);                 // Returns the value
alert(movie);         // Returns [object Object]. I was expecting {title: '<SOMETITLE>', year: '<SOMEYEAR>'}
console.log(movie);   // This prints a lot of stuff and title and year are there with the respective values.

movie.save()
.then(function(object) {
  alert("yay! it worked");  
})
}
</script>
```

Note that when I try to save only the title to the table, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some time I found out what the problem was. And it was a silly one. It turns out that the value in option was of type 'string'. By adding **parseInt()** like so: `var $yearValue = parseInt($select.val());`. And *then* `movie.save({title: titleValue, year: yearValue}).....` This way everything works. Initially, I had tried putting key-value pairs in the save() but the year value wasn't the right type.
 So note to anyone out there - check your data types!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full code, I can't guarantee that this will work, but give this a try:

```
movie.save({
    title : $titleValue,
    year  : $yearValue,
}, {
    success: function(movie) {
        alert("movie saved successfully with title: " + movie.get("title") + 
            ", and year: " + movie.get("year"));
    }, 
    error: function(error) {
        alert("error, movie save failed. error code: " + error.code + ", " error.message);
    }
});
```

At the very least you will have a descriptive error message that will tell you what went wrong. Based on the fact that you said it works when you only save the title and not the year, I suspect it may be because your 'year' field in Parse is stored as a number, but you are passing it in as a string (since it came from an HTML form, I'm assuming).

If that doesn't work, I also suspect it may have something to do with appending this function to your button onload rather than as a click or a submit. But that wouldn't explain why it still works if you just leave out the year.

Finally, I wonder if Parse's SDK is confused by the '$' symbol at the beginning of your variable names, but I don't see why that would be the case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
This still doesn't work. It's not from $. And the error I get(visible in the console) is **400 (Bad Request)**:  http://i.imgur.com/wXZuQmO.png
 Could be something with the parse, I guess.